# *Highchart* tooltips format

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip

I have an area percent chart similar to this example: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked-percent.

Everytime I point my mouse to the graph, the tooltip show all the values which located in the same column, for example: Asia, Africa, America,.... I want to ask is it possible to format the tooltip so that it display only the value of the point that my mouse point to, for example when I point to Asia, it display only the value for Asia and so on, not all the values in the same column

And one more thing with the tooltips is even when I point my mouse outside of the graph, the tooltips still be displayed like this: [image]. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `shared`-Property of the tooltip to false (or remove it completely, since 'false' is the default) then it will only be shown for individual points.

```
tooltip: {
  shared: false
}
```